# Data too long Mysql and python

Tags: python, mysql

MYSQL Error  , while sending from android  to python the GPS Latitude and longititude

```
enter code here

def pacman(self):

     while True:

      while True:

        try:
            x1=self.sockfd.recv(2048)
            print x1
            print "\n hi"
            conn.begin()
            x.execute("UPDATE location SET x='%s'"%(x1))
            print "hi"
            y1=self.sockfd.recv(2048)
            print y1
            x.execute("UPDATE location SET y='%s'"%(y1))
            conn.commit()

        except ValueError:
                   self.sockfd.send("\nError202:That is not a valid Car Number")
```

DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'y' at row 1")  // data appear 
31.3363510530.0845932431.3363510530.0845932431.33635105 !!
Despite not every time its do so what should be done ?

Comment: what exactly is the create table statement for your location table?

Comment: Id ( primary key ) X and Y and X and Y are VarChar (45)

Comment: the string of numbers you stated above is 55 characters in length. 55 being greater than 45 thus the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `varchar 256` it looks like a `mysql` error

Comment: OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction') what about this error

Answer (score 0):

Change your column definition so all possible values fit in it.

Comment: Its Varchar(45 ) and i'm receiving String What should be done

Comment: the string of numbers OP stated is 55 characters in length